# autoreconf -vfi doesn't work properly

Tags: linux, ubuntu, autoconf, autoreconf

I am trying to install a library on Ubuntu 14.04 which requires the following command:

```
autoreconf -vfi
```

The output is

```
Usage: autoreconf [-f] [-h] [--help] [-m dir] [--macrodir=dir]
   [-l dir] [--localdir=dir] [--force] [--verbose] [--version]
   [--cygnus] [--foreign] [--gnits] [--gnu] [-i] [--include-deps]
```

Why am I getting this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed by reinstalling autoconf.